# Matching multiple words within a string with regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I am using Python to match a few words within a sentence and testing them against unit tests. I want a **regular expression** that matches all these words and gives me these outputs mentioned below:

```
firstword = "<p>This is @Timberlake</p>"
outputfirstword = "@Timberlake"
```

Finds the word that starts with the @ symbol

```
secondword = "<p>This is @timber.lake</p>"
outputsecondword = "@timber.lake"
```

Period between words are okay.

```
thirdword = "This is @Timberlake. Yo!"
outputthirdword = "@Timberlake"
```

If there is a space after the period then both the period and space don't count towards the `outputthirdword`

```
fourthword = "This is @Timberlake."
outputfourthword = "@Timberlake"
```

The final period (.) is not included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using this regex:

```
(?i)@[a-z.]+\b
```

You are able to extract the needed part by using capturing groups.
**[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/aA2dA9/2)**

*Explanations:*

```
(?i)     # Enabling case-insensitive modifier
@        # Literal @
[a-z.]   # Match letters a to z as well as a period
\b       # Ending at a word boundary
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@[a-zA-Z]+\b(?:\.[a-zA-Z]+\b)?
```

You can use this.[See demo.](https://regex101.com/r/bN8dL3/2#python)

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'@[a-zA-Z]+\b(?:\.[a-zA-Z]+\b)?')
test_str = "This is @Timberlake. Yo!\n<p>This is @timber.lake</p>"

re.findall(p, test_str)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is using following regex and strip the result with dot :

```
@[a-zA-Z.]+
```

For example if you use `re.search` you can do :

```
re.search(r'@[a-zA-Z.]+','my_string').group(0).strip('.')
```

And you can use following regex that doesn't need `strip` :

```
@[a-zA-Z]+.?[a-zA-Z]+
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wK9zG7/1)

Answer (score 0):

As @Kasra mention, the regex works nice.
But it will not remove the dot in the end.

Use the regex below and i believe that it is what you expect.

```
@[a-zA-Z.]+[a-zA-Z]+
```

See an example below, it is not in Python, but the regex should be the same.

```
$ (echo "<p>This is @Timberlake</p>"; echo "<p>This is @timber.lake</p>"; echo "This is @Timberlake."; echo "<p>This is @tim.ber.lake</p>") | grep -Eo '@[a-zA-Z.]+[a-zA-Z]+'
@Timberlake
@timber.lake
@Timberlake
@tim.ber.lake
```